# Parsing MIDI file to note events

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, naudio

I am currently trying to parse MIDI files to create note events using the NAudio MIDI library, that can be used to allow a virtual piano to play along with a MIDI track. I have a class that should do this, however, there is an error that I can't figure out. Here is the class in its current form:

```
public MidiFile midi;

public float ticks;
public float offset;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    //Loading midi file "mainSong.bytes" from resources folder
    //Its a midi file, extension has been changed to .bytes manually
    TextAsset asset = Resources.Load("mainSong") as TextAsset;
    Stream s = new MemoryStream(asset.bytes);
    //Read the file
    midi = new MidiFile(s, true);
    //Ticks needed for timing calculations
    ticks = midi.DeltaTicksPerQuarterNote;
}

public void StartPlayback()
{
    foreach (MidiEvent note in midi.Events)
    {
        //If its the start of the note event
        if (note.CommandCode == MidiCommandCode.NoteOn)
        {
            //Cast to note event and process it
            NoteOnEvent noe = (NoteOnEvent)note;
            NoteEvent(noe);
        }
    }
}

public void NoteEvent(NoteOnEvent noe)
{
    //The bpm(tempo) of the track
    float bpm = 150;

    //Time until the start of the note in seconds
    float time = (60 * noe.AbsoluteTime) / (bpm * ticks);

    int noteNumber = noe.NoteNumber;

    //Start coroutine for each note at the start of the playback
    StartCoroutine(CreateAction(time, noteNumber, noe.NoteLength));
}

IEnumerator CreateAction(float t, int noteNumber, float length)
{
    //Wait for the start of the note
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(t);
    //The note is about to play, do stuff here
    Debug.Log("Playing note: "+noteNumber);
}
```

Currently, when trying to build this code there is an error in the Start method at the line 
`midi = new MidiFile(s, true);`
The error is **"cannot convert from system.io.stream to string"**

Parsing **s** as a string `midi = new MidiFile(s.ToString(), true);` allows the code to build, however, when running the Unity project the same line gives this error: **"Could not find file "D:\USER PROFILE\Documents\Unity Projects\New Unity Project\System.IO.MemoryStream"**

Does anyone have any idea how to fix either of these errors to allow this code to run in Unity?

Comment: i think you can do `asset.text` btw if u just want the textasset as a string

Comment: @mad.meesh: no, it expects a file name, not the contents

Comment: @ThomasWeller ah ok i don’t know what this library is so i was just saying in general... since he was going from a `textasset` to a `stream` to a `string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking in the [source code](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio/Midi/MidiFile.cs) you can find a constructor that satisfies the `Stream, bool` signature:

```
/// <summary>
/// Opens a MIDI file stream for reading
/// </summary>
/// <param name="inputStream">The input stream containing a MIDI file</param>
/// <param name="strictChecking">If true will error on non-paired note events</param>
public MidiFile(Stream inputStream, bool strictChecking) :
    this(inputStream, strictChecking, false)
{
}
```

It seems you're using an old version of the library. Back in 2013, NAudio did not support playing MIDIs from a stream.

Looking into the history, it seems that Stream support was added on 2017-04-15.

You should try to find a newer version, e.g. install a newer NuGet package.

---

`s.ToString()` will definitely not help you, because:

- it converts the `Stream` object into its human readable format. Except for some special objects, it will usually be the class name. In your case, the class name is `System.IO.MemoryStream` (that's the type of `s`).
- it will then look for **a file** called `System.IO.memoryStream` in the current directory. The current directory  is `D:\User\...\New Unity Project`.
- Of course there will be no file, since you have a resource, not a file.